# How to get a particular cell value on that cell click in my toolkit datagrid?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, uwp, mytoolkit

I am using Mytoolkit datagrid in my uwp windows app. I found that here https://github.com/MyToolkit/MyToolkit/wiki/DataGrid and in that grid I want a particular cell value when that cell is clicked.

I tried like this but data is not binding and displaying

```
<controls:DataGridTemplatedColumn  d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=models:SkuList}" CanSort="False" > 
                                    <controls:DataGridTemplatedColumn.Header>
                                        <Button x:Uid="RQty" Height="40" Width="110"  Style="{StaticResource RoundButtonTemplate}"  Margin="-10,0,0,0"/>
                                    </controls:DataGridTemplatedColumn.Header>
                                    <controls:DataGridTemplatedColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <StackPanel Width="20" Height="30">
                                                <TextBlock Name="quantity" Text='{Binding quantity}' VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,5,0,0"></TextBlock>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </controls:DataGridTemplatedColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </controls:DataGridTemplatedColumn>
```

can any one tell me the way to get a cell value on that cell click?

Answer (score 0):

Using DataTemplate.

```
  <controls:DataGridTemplatedColumn>
                                        <controls:DataGridTemplatedColumn.Header>
                                            <Button x:Uid="RQty" Height="40" Width="110"  Style="{StaticResource RoundButtonTemplate}"  Margin="-10,0,0,0"/>
                                        </controls:DataGridTemplatedColumn.Header>
                                        <controls:DataGridTemplatedColumn.CellTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <StackPanel Width="20" Height="30" Tapped="StackPanel_Tapped" >
                                                    <TextBlock Name="quantity" Foreground="White"  Text='{Binding quantity}' VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,5,0,0"></TextBlock>
                                                </StackPanel>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </controls:DataGridTemplatedColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    </controls:DataGridTemplatedColumn>
```